# Why doesn't postinstall run every time?

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, npm

I have a package.json file that has the following JSON at the bottom.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": [
      "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
    ]
  }
```

My reason for having this is so bower dependencies and my protractor tests will run after an "npm install". However, it seems that "postinstall" doesn't always run. I'm trying to get everything setup on Jenkins, so I'd like to be able to run the following commands and be good to go.

```
npm install
grunt jenkins
```

The jenkins task calls tasks to build, test, and run e2e tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the command from an array to a string.

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  }
```